# Touchpad does not work for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Lenovo Legion Y730

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I recently bought this laptop. Everything work perfect with windows, but when I install Ubuntu 16.04, the touchpad does not work. External mouse works great. I tried everything I could online, nothing is helping. Anyone facing the same issue? Should I try other Ubuntu versions like 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it, and believe me this is most probably the only solution; I tried every other things on-line, nothing worked.

First I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, but it did not solve the problem.

Then I installed ukuu to upgrade kernel.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Then with ukuu:

```
ukuu --install v4.19.10
```

Then

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now see the magic :)

Comment: This answer is very specific for Lenovo Legion Y730. I don't know if that would be true for others.